# Why did the Engineers' Home world appear so primitive?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, alien-covenant

In the movie *Prometheus*, we see what appears to be an advanced race the 'Engineers' travel throughout space, they seem to be able to create life or at least cultivate it very well.   Yet we see when David and Dr. Shaw reach the home world in *Alien Covenant*, the garb of the citizens, the buildings, all seem primitive or at least much more primitive than you would think for such an advanced space travel race.

There is of course some impressive docking structure, but beyond that and throughout the rest of the movie when they are in what David calls the 'Necropolis', everything feels very simple.

Yes there is some sort of internal lighting, which suggests some technology, but I guess I expected to see a much more advanced infrastructure.  Were there any notes from the director/cast to suggest why they went this way with the home world?

Comment: It's not their home world - it's some remote outpost with just one facility on it. Presumably, some sort of military bio-engineering research facility. Kind of facility where nothing can possibly go wrong, ever...

Comment: The bio-engineering research facility is not the city featured in Covenant, which is what the OP is asking about. If memory serves me, the Necropolis was just a planet of a species created by the Engineers.

Comment: @HansOlo seems like your comment is indeed a reasonable answer. I do not know if my message can reach 5 years back in time. If it does reach you, I have much to tell you.